# How to save a datepicker into databse in laravel 5.4?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-5, datepicker

I want save the date into the database. But i get error saying my date is null.

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {

  $slot = new Slot;
  $slot->ps_name = Auth::guard('ps')->user()->name;
  $slot->date = $request->date;
  $slot->time = $request->time;
  $slot->area = $request->area;
  $slot->duration = $request->duration;


  $slot->save();
 return view('pshome');
 }
```

Slot database

```
  Schema::create('slot', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('ps_name');
        $table->DateTime('date');
        $table->integer('time');
        $table->integer('duration');
        $table->string('area');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all field type on the table is "datetime"(lowercase) for both date and time and "date" if you only store date. Then assuming your date time format on `$request` is "m/d/Y",

if date field on table is both date and time(i.e: 2017-09-11 10:00:00)

`$slot->date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $request->date)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

if date field on table is only date(i.e: 2017-09-11)

`$slot->date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $request->date)->format('Y-m-d');`

if date on the request `$request` is in "Y-m-d H:i:s" or "Y-m-d"(depending on the field type) you can directly assign.(Same as your method)

Comment: i get an error of (1/1) InvalidArgumentException Data missing. What is mean by data missing ?

Comment: data missing means the date format you used in `createFromFormat` and actual format on request are different. so add a `dd($request->date);`  and find the correct format that is on the request